# Detect camera rotation on Microsoft Surface?

Tags: windows, camera, ms-media-foundation, surface-pro

Is there a reliable way to determine if a camera is rotated on the Microsoft Surface?

Basically, I want to know if a specific camera is built into the device (as it will then rotate with the device), is there a way to query this?

My problem is that when the user rotates the device, my camera view is flipped, I cannot however assume that I should just rotate the read frames as the active camera may be an external USB camera.

I'm reading the cameras using the Media Foundation APIs.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this will help, but you can check the MF_MT_DEFAULT_STRIDE attribute of the camera's media type: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms698965(v=vs.85).aspx. 
"Stride is positive for top-down images, and negative for bottom-up images."

Comment: I don't think that's it, for example, the device may rotate 90 degrees. :(

Comment: It's rather [`MF_MT_VIDEO_ROTATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162880) but I am not sure if Surface camera is actually using it.

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, I want to know if a specific camera is built into the device [...] is there a way to query this?

With UWP, you can check the camera's [`DeviceInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.aspx)'s [`enclosureLocation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.enclosurelocation.aspx).[`panel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.enclosurelocation.panel.aspx) property, which is either:

- `front`/`back`/etc for an integrated camera or
- `unknown` for an external camera

An full example is available in the [CameraStarterKit](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit) sample.

---

**However**, if you can't use UWP, it should still be possible to find the underlying information.  With MF, you should be able to access [`MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388685(v=vs.85).aspx).

This will be something like

```
\\?\usb#vid_046d&pid_0843&mi_00#6&2314864d&0&0000#{e5323777-f976-4f5b-9b55-b94699c46e44}\global
```

A built-in camera is [supposed to register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn394066(v=vs.85).aspx) its physical location in

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\InternalDeviceModification\{GUID}
```

Where the value of the [`PLD_Panel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn394066(v=vs.85).aspx#PLD_PANEL_DETAILS) key should be a DWORD with values very similar to the `Panel` enum referenced above.

Here, `6` means `unknown`. So you should be able to check for the presence of this registry key and, if present check its value.  I suspect this is similar to what UWP does under the hood.

Failing that, you can also hack in support by hardcoding some values for camera vendor and product ID's or [`MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_FRIENDLY_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388678(v=vs.85).aspx)'s.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need. Excellent! However, when looking in regedit on my Surface Pro 3 device (running windows 10) the InternalDeviceModification key is missing. Any ideas?